# Flink Operator High Availability - Service is temporarily unavailable due to ongoing leader election

Tags: kubernetes, apache-flink

I install on my kubernetes cluster a flink operator (Version 1.3.1).
Now when I tried to set up flink deployment object on my kubernetes the operator work as expected and run my job (Flink Version 1.16).
Now when I set the same deployment with High Availability with this configuration:

```yaml
high-availabilty: kubernetes
high-availabilty.storageDir: file:///mnt/flink/recovery
high-availabilty.cluster-id: flink-operator-poc
```

- There's pvc mounted in the configuration to "mnt/flink"
- The cluster-id is unique

When I run with a singal job Manger the deployment run as expected and I can acsess the UI with a route I created to the generated service.

When I delete the job Manger to mock a failed job Manger it recover automatically and same with a task manger failure.

Now when I create the same deployment but with 2.
At the start the job working as expected but when I kill the job Manger the following thing happens:

1. The UI won't show and the message `Service temporarily unavailable due to onging leader election.`
2. The operator create 2 additional taskmangers And delete old ones after 5 minutes and start all over again becuse of the error. In all the taskmangers There's the same error of: `Could not resolve ResourceManger address`
   `Could not connect to rpc endpoint under address akka.tcp://flink@IP:6123/user/rpc/resourcemanager_0.`
   `Remote connection to [null] failed with java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host`
   `Association with remote system [akka.tcp://flink@IP:6123] has failed, address is now gated for [50] ms. Reasone: [Association failed with [akka.tcp://flink@IP:6123]] Caused by: [java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host]`

> The 'IP' has a real value (Just for here I wrote 'IP'

Same with 3 or more job manager.

Sometimes the the deployment will work as expected and sometimes the errors I described above occurred.

How can I check that kubernetes HA work as expected. Aside from seen the `cluster-config-map` (Because it's look ok)

Answer (score 0):

As per [Yang Wang](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-20798), currently for standalone Flink on K8s, we could set the kubernetes.namespace same as the namespace we are deploying the JobManager and TaskManager pods to work around. For native Flink on K8s, we do not have this issue. Because we are always creating the HA ConfigMaps in the same namespace as the JobManager/TaskManager pods.
 
You can use [this](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-kubernetes/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/kubernetes/kubeclient/Fabric8FlinkKubeClient.java#L344) as a reference.